# Android call method from another activity

Tags: java, android

How would I call a method from a different activity?
In my main activity, I have a button that shows a dialog to set the difficulty level of the game.
Then you click start game which starts a new activity containing a view with all the game information.
I need to send the difficulty level chosen to the other activity but cannot seem to figure out how to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put it in the extras with the intent:

```
Intent StartGame = new Intent(this, StartGame.class);
StartGame.putExtra("difficulty", difficultyLevel);
startActivity(StartGame);
```

Then in your StartGame.class you can retrive it like this(assuming its a string):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String difficulty= extras.getString("difficulty");
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it the same way atm but isn't there an other way? So you can directly call a method from the activity where you start the intent from instead of first checking for GetExtras() in the destination activity and then calling a method.

Answer (score 6):

Well I don't know how sound my solution is but I created a myApplication class which sub classes the Application class .

This holds the reference to the activity I wanted to call

```
import android.app.Application;

public class myApplication extends Application {
    public PostAndViewActivity pv;
}
```

When the PostAndViewActivity calls the oncreate is sets the pv to point to itself.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((myApplication) getApplication()).pv = this;
```

Then when I want to call the method I want I just use code like this:

```
((myApplication) getApplication()).pv.refreshYourself();
```

Perhaps a bit hacky but it works.....
I welcome some critisism for this ;-)